# I would like prove a result in integration

Tags: integration, analysis

I would like prove this result

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\left(\log (1+x)\right)^2}{x}\mathrm dx=\frac{\zeta(3)}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

note that 
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\ln^{2}(1+x)}{x} \, dx = - 2 \, Li_{3}(1+x) + 2 \, Li_{2}(1+x) \, \ln(1+x) + \ln(-x)  \, \ln^{2}(1+x)
\end{align}
for which
\begin{align}
I_{2} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^{2}(1+x)}{x} \, dx = \frac{\zeta(3)}{4}.
\end{align}

Comment: thank you !   i use this result

Answer (score 0):

Another derivation is the following one:
$$-\log(1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{n},$$
$$-\frac{\log(1-z)}{1-z}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}H_n z^n,$$
$$\frac{d}{dz}\log^2(1-z)=-2\frac{\log(1-z)}{1-z}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}2H_n z^n,$$
$$\log^2(1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2H_n}{n+1}z^{n+1},$$
$$I_2=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(1+z)}{z}\,dz = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2H_n(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2},$$
where the last series can be verified to be equal to $\frac{1}{4}\zeta(3)$ by following [this precious link](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse13.php#x15-12200013).